# next() function for my on linkedlist class

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm making my own linkedlist class for an exercise I'm doing, and I'm unsure about the next() function I'm using works as I intend. The way I want it to work is for it to start from the first node in the list and then follow links to the following nodes until it reaches the last node in the list.

```
    private class MyIterator implements java.util.Iterator<MyNode<E>> {

        private MyNode<E> current = firstNode;
        private int acceptableModCnt = modCount;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current.next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public MyNode<E> next() {

            if (modCnt != acceptableModCnt) {
                throw new java.util.ConcurrentModificationException( );
            }
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException( );
            }

            MyNode<E> nextNode = current.next;
            current = current.next;
            return nextNode;
        }
    }
```

Have I implemented the next() function correctly?

Comment: Where do you define `modCnt` and where does it get modified?

Comment: I define modified as 0 to begin with, and then it gets ++ everytime I remove or add an element.

Comment: How does it differ from `modCount` and `acceptableModCnt`. Please show enough context. Without that we cannot say if this code is good or not. Apparently `modCount` never changes, and is always equal to `acceptableModCnt`. Does the latter ever change?

Comment: modCount changes when I add or remove an element in the linked list, so when I create an iterator object I cannot use it if the list has been modified in any way since its creation.

Comment: What is the difference between `modCount` and `modCnt`? Seems the explanation you give for them is exactly the same...